# Smarty Date Difference

Tags: smarty

Please post any smarty syntax to Get number of days between two dates from my database. i was to able to display all the other fields,but this date field with number of days not working as the way i was expected.Please let me know is there any way to get this solution without any smarty additional plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Smarty does not include any specific functions for doing date math operations. They have the [`date_format`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/tips.dates.tpl) for timestamps, but otherwise you'd either have to write your own `days_diff` plugin, find one online, or do the date math in PHP and assign to a new variable in Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function for this problem:

```
/* 
* Smarty plugin 
* ------------------------------------------------------------- 
* Type: function 
* Name: date_diff 
* Author: Rafał Pawlukiewicz
* Purpose: factor difference between two dates in days, weeks, or years
* Input: d1 = "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy/mm/dd" or "yyyy-mm-dd"
*        d2 = "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy/mm/dd" or "yyyy-mm-dd" or $smarty.now
*        assign = name of variable to assign difference to 
*        interval = "days" (default), "weeks", "years" 
* Examples: {date_diff d1="2020-01-20"}
* Examples: {date_diff d1="2020-01-20" d2=2020-02-10 interval="weeks"}
* Examples: {date_diff d1="2020-01-20" d2=2020-02-10 assign="variable_diff"} result: {$variable_diff}
* -------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function smarty_function_date_diff($params, &$smarty)
{
    $d1          = isset($params['d1']) ? $params['d1'] : date('Y-m-d');
    $d2          = isset($params['d2']) ? $params['d2'] : date('Y-m-d');
    $assign_name = isset($params['assign']) ? $params['assign'] : '';

    $date1 = strtotime($d1);
    $date2 = strtotime($d2);

    // use current for empty string
    if (! $date1) {
        $date1 = date('Y-m-d');
    }
    if (! $date2) {
        $date2 = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    $interval = isset($params['interval']) ? $params['interval'] : 'days';

    // diff in days
    $diff = ($date2 - $date1) / 60 / 60 / 24;

    if ($interval === "weeks") {
        $diff /= 7;
    }
    elseif ($interval === "years") {
        $diff /= 365.25;
    }

    $diff = floor($diff);

    if ($assign_name) {
        $smarty->assign($assign_name, $diff);
    }
    else {
        return $diff;
    }

}
```